# retaining PHP variable after re-running the same script

Tags: php, html, ember.js

I'm very new to PHP, and I'm trying to add features to an already existing app.

The following PHP code will be used each time there's a database request from the client side.

```
  <?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    require_once("config/keychain.php");

    function decrypt($data, $key, $iv){
      $key = pack('H*', $key);
      $iv = pack('H*', $iv);
      return mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 , $key , $data ,  
      MCRYPT_MODE_CBC ,  $iv );
    }
    $request = (object)$_REQUEST;
    $dbConfig = (object)parse_ini_string(decrypt(file_get_contents("config/database.ini"), ENCRYPTION_KEY, ENCRYPTION_IV));
    require_once("include/UniversalDB.php");
    require_once("include/UniversalModel.php");
    require_once("include/UniversalController.php");
  /*
    Set DB Connection
  */
    $dbConnection = new UniversalDB();
   $dbConnection->init($dbConfig->host, $dbConfig->user, $dbConfig-
   >password, 2);
   /*$universalDB->connect();*/
   require_once("boot.php");
  ?>
```

I'm trying to maintain one property from one of these requests values(the login $_REQUEST values).

I tried adding this to the previous script.

```
if(property_exists($request,'selectedDatabase')){
  $selectedDatabase = $request->selectedDatabase;
}
```

I will get the `$selectedDatabase` initialized correctly. However, every time this script is running everything gets uninitialized.

I also tried making `$selectedDatabase` in `$GLOBALS` and  making it static,but I lose the value when another request is coming.

Any ideas how can I maintain `$selectedDatabase`?

NOTE: The file where this script is written called `Index.php`, and I'm not sure if it's the first script to load or not. However it seems like it!

Thank you,

Comment: You could try something with sessions.

Comment: thank man I think sessions solved my problem !

Comment: thanks* ..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to persist the value. Here are a couple:

### Session

One way is using PHP's built-in [session handling](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php). There are various ways to store the session data - the default uses files but other means like in a database are supported.

Start by calling [session_start()](http://php.net/session_start). Then utilize the [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) array [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) to get and set the value.

```
$selectedDatabase = null;//initialize to empty value
$sessionStarted = session_start();
if ($sessionStarted) {
    $selectedDatabase = $_SESSION['selectedDatabase'];
}
if ($selectedDatabase) {
    //value is set, use it
}
else {
    //set the value from $request
    if(property_exists($request,'selectedDatabase')){
        $selectedDatabase = $request->selectedDatabase;
    }
    //store the value in the session for subsequent requests
    $_SESSION['selectedDatabase'] = $selectedDatabase;
}
```

See a demonstration in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gdt3-az3e).

### File

Another solution might be to store the value in a file, e.g. using [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents) and [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/file_put_contents), along with [file_exists](http://php.net/file_exists). The contents could also be stored as an object using [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) or another serialize function (e.g. [serialize()](http://php.net/serialize)).

```
$selectedDatabase = null;//initialize to empty value
$fileName = 'databaseConfig.txt'; //set path accordingly
if (file_exists($fileName)) {
    $selectedDatabase = file_get_contents($fileName);
}
if ($selectedDatabase) {
    //value is set, use it
}
else {
    //set the value from $request
    if(property_exists($request,'selectedDatabase')){
        $selectedDatabase = $request->selectedDatabase;
    }
    //store the value in the session for subsequent requests
    file_put_contents($fileName, $selectedDatabase);
}
```